# Missing Icon In Chrome Extension Page (chrome-extension://)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How to change default, "puzzle piece" icon visible on left side of URL bar in Chrome Extension page?

All icons was defined properly in manifest file but this dont fix my problem.

```js
"icons":    {
 
 "16":    "16.png", 
 "32":    "32.png", 
 "48":    "48.png", 
 "128":    "128.png"
}
```

[image: Missing Chrome Extension Page Icon in URL Bar]

Comment: Er, that icon is not customizable, it's a "type" icon. The extension icon is shown in the tab title.

Comment: @wOxxOm this should be the answer.